# How to do pass through from USB to HDMI in Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: usb, hdmi, pi-zero

1. Is it possible to pass through from USB to HDMI in Raspberry Pi Zero W?
2. I need to pass through video/data from my laptop to TV Monitor through Raspberry Pi Zero W while capturing passed data in Raspberry Pi Zero W.

My laptop(HDMI out) ---> (HDMI in) HDMI video capture with adapter (micro USB) ---> (micro USB) Raspberry Pi Zero W with saving to external storage (mini HDMI out) ----> (HDMI in) TV monitor

**The expected resolution and frame rate:** up to 1080p and up to 120HZ (but it can be less, it doesn't matter for now)

**HDMI video capture:** something like this - [https://www.amazon.com/FURUI-Capture-USB2-0-Camcorder-Compatible/dp/B08911TVP9](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08911TVP9)

How can I do this?

**UPDATE:**
I tried this solution: `cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0:chroma=YUYV`
I can see laptop screen, but without sound.

**UPDATE-2:**
This `cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0 :input-slave=alsa://hw:2,0` solved my problem

But, maybe somebody can suggest an another way? How can I set parameters for optimal quality of video?

Comment: I think there's a mistake in the question title: what you describe is HDMI->USB, not USB->HDMI.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. There is no a mistake. HDMI cable connects my laptop with HDMI video capture. HDMI video capture is connected to Raspberry Pi through usb to micro usb adapter. Then an another cable connects mini HDMI out of Raspberry PI to HDMI in of TV monitor. Where is mistake?

Comment: Oh, I got what you mean now. You mean USB to HDMI via the VideoCore. That's pretty much how webcams work. I thought you were looking for a USB->HDMI external video card or something.